# Forge: Access centralized non-published revit model

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api

According to the following link (dated January 2017) Accessing centralized non-published revit model is not possible.
https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/2017/01/26/c4r-and-forge-api-access/

The reason that I am asking again is according to the following link (undated) Forge can be used to publish the centralized non-published model. So, there is must be a connection between centralized model and Forge API.

https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/publish-model/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three places where a Revit model "sits" when using C4R: 1) user's desktop, 2) C4R database, and 3) Team or Docs storage. "synchronize with central" only updates #1 to #2. "publish" uploads #2 to #3. Forge API on the Forge developer page is about #2 to #3, i.e., publishing a centralized model to Docs. Forge API supports only Docs, not Team.

Side note: Revit 2018.3 supports Team and Docs. Revit 2019 supports Docs only.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed Forge now supports BIM 360 Design (formerly Collaboration for Revit, C4R) models. It also supports [model.publish](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/http/model.publish/) and [model.sync](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/http/model.sync/) webhook events.

Comment: Thanks Augusto, but what about accessing (e.g. downloading) the most recent central model which might not be published?

Comment: models are versioned, so you need to get the download URL for the last version (or another version), is that it?

Comment: I tried to get the latest version but it didn't work. Let's say the version of the file in BIM360 is v3 and I open the file in Revit and make changes then synced with the central file (without publishing). At this moment, BIM360 and forge tip version still v3. This can be verified using step 5 in the following link.
https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/publish-model/

Now the question can I access the centralized model (changes after v3) without publish it (step 6 in previous link)?

Comment: if I'm understanding your question, you need to `Publish` to view on the cloud, see https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Revit-CAR/files/GUID-AE6DBCDF-3DB1-41CB-9DC5-B0C336E6C851-htm.html

Comment: Thanks Augusto, maybe we need an input from revit expert, because I can confirm that other team members can see the changes without having to publish the model (i.e. the central model is hosted on the cloud and it can be accessed from revit (once synced but not from Forge till it is explicitly published)

Comment: I know it's a bit complicated till we understand what is going on. There are three places where a revit model "sits" when using C4R: 1) user's desktop, 2) C4R database, 3) Team or Docs storage. "synchronize with central" only updates #1 to #2. "publish" upload #2 to #3.  Forge API supports only Docs, not Team.